# How to show Splash Screen when internet connection is off? Android

Tags: android

I want to show a full screen image when the Internet is down so the user can't use the app is he has no Internet connectivity. I am thinking to use a broadcast receiver like this one:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
            if (extras.get("EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY") == true) {
              //show splash screen
            }

    }
}
```

And when the if instruction is true to show the splash screen.

Please tell me if this is right and how I can show that splash screen.

Comment: You can show a transparent overlay fragment indicating Internet is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This is how you could do it:

1.: create a NetworkChangeReceiver with a callback if the network changes

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NetworkLostCallback mNetworkLostCallback;

public interface NetworkLostCallback {
    public void onNetworkLost();
    public void onNetworkRegained();
}

public void setNetworkLostCallback(NetworkLostCallback callback) {
    mNetworkLostCallback = callback;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (mNetworkLostCallback != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null
                && (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
            mNetworkLostCallback.onNetworkRegained();
        } else {
            mNetworkLostCallback.onNetworkLost();
        }
    }
}
```

}

2.: register the receiver and the callback

```
mNetworkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
mNetworkChangeReceiver.setNetworkLostCallback(this);

IntentFilter networkFilter = new IntentFilter();
networkFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

getActivity().registerReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver, networkFilter);
```

3.: listen for changes and display a dialog if the network gets lost.

```
public void onNetworkLost() {
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DisconnectedDialog.class.getSimpleName());
    if (f == null) {
        DisconnectedDialog dialog = DisconnectedDialog.newInstance();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), DisconnectedDialog.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Done.

it is up to you, if you open a dialog or another activity.